# Update Windows 7 via cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, command, cmd

I need to automate the updating/installation of MS patches in some remote machines.
I can't use MDT because there is already a different subsystem handling mass software/patch distribution on all the workstations.

Therefore the easiest/fastest way would be to connect with a script to each machine and run a command (if it exists) that would start updating the system just as if a user had clicked Control Panel/Windows Update/Update now...

I searched and found the wuauclt utility which I try to run on a machine and check if it works and it just doesn't do anything.

I tried doing

```
wuauclt /a /detectnow
```

and then

```
wuauclt /r
```

It doesn't report that "The command does not exist" or anything like that. It just doesn't output anything at all and I see no updates being installed in the background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read [this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_8724332_use-powershell-run-windows-updates.html) yesterday, I think it might be able to help you. Please give it a look and let me know if it helps.

```
http://www.ehow.com/how_8724332_use-powershell-run-windows-updates.html
```